# Python - what is difference in os.popen and subprocess.Popen?

Tags: process, python

Python - what is difference in os.popen and subprocess.Popen?

Answer (score 6):

The `os` process functionality is considered obsolete. The `subprocess` module was introduced in Python 2.4 as a unified, more powerful replacement for several older modules and functions related to subprocesses. They are listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#):

- `os.system`
- `os.spawn*`
- `os.popen*`
- `popen2.*`
- `commands.*`

`os.popen` was deprecated in Python 2.6 (but, interestingly, it is not deprecated in Python 3, where [it is implemented in terms of `subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen)). There is a paragraph in the documentation on [how to replace it with `subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3).

Comment: // , If the os process functionality is increasingly obsolete, then what new techniques from subprocess replace methods like `os.getcwd()`, `os.chdir()`, and `os.path`??

Comment: @NathanBasanese These are not process functions. The `subprocess` module is only about subprocesses, it does not replace the whole `os` module.

Comment: @techtonik That was true, I added some info.

Comment: Probably the reason why `os.popen` is not deprecated in Python 3 is the performance - http://essays.ajs.com/2011/02/python-subprocess-vs-ospopen-overhead.html

Comment: @anatolytechtonik In Python 3, it is implemented using `subprocess.Popen`, so it's likely slower and definitely less powerful.